# divs' horizontal alignment erratic in container div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to have 4 divs aligned horizontally in a parent div. The parent div has width:100%;

All child divs have width:20%; I want the remaining 20% to be empty space, distributed evenly between them (around 7% between every two divs).

I have tried this code:

```
<div id="header" style="position:absolute; width:90%; border:2px solid black;">
    <div id="h_left" style="left:0; border:1px dotted black; width:20%;"> Left side material </div>
    <div id="h_center1" style="margin:auto; border:1px dotted black; width:20%;"> Center 1 material </div>
    <div id="h_center2" style="margin:auto; border:1px dotted black; width:20%;"> Center 2 material </div>
    <div id="h_right" style="right:0; border:1px dotted black; width:20%;"> Right side material </div>
</div>
```

But this produces a very disappointing result:
[image]

How can I improve my code so that all divs are aligned accordingly with equal space between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are a display [`block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) by standard. This means that each one will be on its own line. I recommend doing a 1 hour free starter course on CSS that will help you with all these assumptions.

You can do what you want to style this, there are many options. But I recommend flex box. Flex box and Grid will be your friends in CSS. Here is a [simple guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) I still reference.

```html
    <div
      style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; position:absolute; width:90%; border:2px solid black;"
    >
      <div id="h_left">Left side material</div>
      <div id="h_center1">Center 1 material</div>
      <div id="h_center2">Center 2 material</div>
      <div id="h_right">Right side material</div>
    </div>
```

here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-paper-pzglh?file=/index.html:262-600) that shows it

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thanks. Can you point me to the "1 hour free CSS course" you mentioned above?

Comment: Yah I used https://www.codecademy.com/learn to get free courses on CSS and HTML. It was worth it. You learn basics. They charge eventually , but the basics are well worth it. CSS has about 2^20th gotchas.  But this will cover the basics that will help you understand display and things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Make it simple use `flex` and make content `justify-between` it will align the space exactly same between buttons:

1. [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)
2. [Justity-between](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)

You can also try using `justify-around` property, if you go through the above links which will help you what to choose for your requirement.

```css
#header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#h_left {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 20%;
}

#h_center1 {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 20%;
}

#h_center2 {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 20%;
}

#h_right {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="h_left"> Left side material </div>
  <div id="h_center1"> Center 1 material </div>
  <div id="h_center2"> Center 2 material </div>
  <div id="h_right"> Right side material </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```html
<div id="header" style="position:absolute; width:90%; border:2px solid black;">
    <div id="h_left" style="left:0; border:1px dotted black; width:20%; float: left;"> Left side material </div>
    <div id="h_center1" style="margin-left:6.6%; border:1px dotted black; width:20%; float: left;"> Center 1 material </div>
    <div id="h_center2" style="margin-left:6.6%; border:1px dotted black; width:20%; float: left;"> Center 2 material </div>
    <div id="h_right" style="right:0; border:1px dotted black; width:20%; float: right;"> Right side material </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

#header > div {
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="h_left"> Left side material </div>
  <div id="h_center1"> Center 1 material </div>
  <div id="h_center2"> Center 2 material </div>
  <div id="h_right"> Right side material </div>
</div>
```